# Using Posts API to create a post to an organization

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am migrating from using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts` to `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts`.

The UgcPosts API call to create a post in the organization works:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
Header: X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:73873366",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "Share commentary text."
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
            "media": [
                {
                    "status": "READY",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "Description text."
                    },
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:D4D22AQHZkwZQ-pS_AQ",
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Title text."
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

The response is `201 Created` giving me `{ "id": "urn:li:share:7069267959319339009" }`.

However if I use the new posts API it complains (I am following the [official documentation Single Post Creation Sample Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http#single-post-creation-sample-request):

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
Header: X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Header: LinkedIn-Version: 202305
{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:73873366",
  "commentary": "My cool image.",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
    "targetEntities": [],
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "content": {
    "media": {
      "title":"Name of the image",
      "id": "urn:li:image:D4D22AQHZkwZQ-pS_AQ"
    }
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}
```

The response I get is `400 Bad Request`:

```
{
    "message": "Organization permissions must be used when using organization as author",
    "status": 400
}
```

By reading the documentation I could not figure out what are the steps needed. I tried getting information with the `/rest/organizationAuthorizations` endpoint as described in [LinkedIn Documentation Organization Authorizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-authorizations/organization-authorizations) but it gives me problems.

I am trying [get-organization-authorization-information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-authorizations/organization-authorizations?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http#get-organization-authorization-information) as described in the documentation follows:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationAuthorizations/(impersonator:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3ASnbx29l-ix,organization:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A73873366,action:(organizationRoleAuthorizationAction:(actionType:ADMINISTRATOR_READ)))
Header: X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Header: LinkedIn-Version: 202305
```

Which yields a `400 Bad Request`:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "code": "ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "Syntax exception in path variables"
}
```

I believe there's a problem in the documentation.

These are the permissions with the token I am playing with:

```
POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/introspectToken
Header: X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
{ "token": "...", "client_id": "...", "secret": "..."}
```

Response:

```
{
    "active": true,
    "client_id": "...",
    "authorized_at": 1685445569,
    "created_at": 1685445569,
    "status": "active",
    "expires_at": 1690629570,
    "scope": "r_emailaddress,r_liteprofile,r_member_live,r_organization_admin,r_organization_live,w_member_live,w_member_social,w_organization_live",
    "auth_type": "3L"
}
```

My concerts summarized:

- What would be the proper migration of the UgcPosts API -> Posts API?
- What does `Organization permissions must be used when using organization as author` mean? Do I need to pass a separate token? The user I am playing with has admin access to the organization I'm using. Should I perhaps tweak the Organization permissions with the LinkedIn UI?
- Do I need more OAuth permissions?
- Can I keep using the legacy UgcPosts API? It doesn't seem to work with the unversioned `/v2/ -> /rest/` migration. Will it be sunset?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if you included in your OAuth2 scopes `w_organization_social` you should be able to create posts with the new APIs just like you did with the unversioned ones, meaning without any new permission.

That said, I had a similar problem where on my own account, using new tokens with all scopes enabled, the `rest/posts` endpoint kept erroring.

This is probably because the only `/v2` APIs that are [going to sunset on June 30](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-unversioned)in favor of the `/rest` (versioned) ones are the Marketing APIs.

If you post, you're using the Share on LinkedIn APIs which don't seem fully functional in their `/rest` form. This also means that you don't need to transition to the new APIs.

Anyways, one *possible* workaround that I haven't tested yet could be to add every organization scope (`rw_organization_admin`, `r_organization_social`, `w_organization_social`, `r_organization_admin`).

I think what could be going on is that you can't create a post if you don't have the `r_organization_admin` permission as well. Still, this is just a hypothesis.

I'll message their support on ZenDesk to see if they have a better answer.

**TL;DR: No, the consumer unversioned APIs will not sunset anytime soon. I encountered a similar problem on a personal profile.**

Comment: Thanks for the advice and your intuitions. I sent a message to LinkedIn. I cannot add these permissions because we only can ask for the `r_organization_admin,r_organization_live,w_organization_live`. They asked us to create another App, get the permissions through a review through that App, and then remove that App and keep using the App we currenly have. That way we would have those permissions that you listed `rw_organization_admin`, `r_organization_social`, `w_organization_social`, `r_organization_admin`. When I have time I'll give it a go and update this post.